# Recorrer elementos de arreglo Javascript como en C++ 11

Tags: javascript

En javascript se puede recorrer un arreglo como se hace en otros lenguajes como C++ 11, por ejemplo de esta manera:

```
for(auto i : array) {
   // imprimir i
}
```

Con javascript he podido hacer esto:

```
for(var i in array) {
   // imprimir array[i]
}
```

El asunto es que i no contiene el items actual del arreglo sino el indice, lo que pregunto es si fuese posible que i apuntara al un valor del arreglo en cada pasada como lo hace C++ 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta utilizar [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of)

```js
for (var i of [1,2,3,4]) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Existen muchas formas de recorrer un array por medio de JavaScript, acá te dejo unos cuantos métodos:

**Usando ciclo for in**

```js
var array = [10,20,30,40,50];

for(var i in array) {
   console.log(array[i])
}
```

**Usando método map**

```js
var array = [10,20,30,40,50];

array.map(function(dato){
  console.log(dato);
});
```

**Usando método forEach**

```js
var array = [10,20,30,40,50];

array.forEach(function(dato){
  console.log(dato);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más común es hacerlo mediante un bucle `for`, aunque se puede hacer de otras meneras. Te dejo dos maneras de hacer un bucle for, la última de ellas está comentada en el script.

```js
var array = ["Hola","que","tal","estas"];

for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
  console.log(array[i]);
}

/*
for (var i in array){
  console.log(array[i]);
}*/
```